# уведомление о каждой новой строке в текстовом файле звуком

Tags: linux, bash

Результатом нескольких долгих процессов является возможное добавление в общий текстовый файл новой строки. Как на bash сделать уведомление в реальном времени о добавлении каждой новой строки скажем звуковым файлом? (например запустить какой-то `mpg123 -q notification.mp3` )  Звук должен зазвучать только при добавлении причем каждой новой строки, а не в конце процессов (он может быть бесконечным), если никакая строка не добавляется, соответственно тишина.
Можно как и включаемый в трубу каждого процесса (все процессы заканчиваются `| tee -a text.txt`, можно как и отдельно параллельно работающий процесс.
Как вариант - отслеживание не строки, а изменение размера файла к примеру, ведь добавление даже одного символа приведет к увеличению в байтах.
Выслушаю все предложения, спасибо.
`tail -f` ? `wc -l` ? `watch` ?

Comment: Закажи для сишников прогу, напишут быстро.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

программа *tail*, будучи запущеной с опцией `-f`, выводит в *stdout* строки, добавляемые в переданный параметром `файл`.

эти строки можно в цикле читать и выполнять на каждой итерации нужную(-ые) вам программу(-ы):

```
$ tail -f файл | while read line; do программа параметры; done
```

Comment: Если запись буферезирована, то может быть тишина, тишина, а потом — пулемёт! Но это к ответу не имеет отношения.

Comment: Да, работает. Спасибо, alexander barakin ! Один раз вылетало `tail: text.txt: file truncated` при опробировании, пока замечено только одно неудобство - если запускается при наличии в текстовом файле строк, особенно когда их немало, придется слушать сначала звук по кол-ву строк. А можно как-то прикрутить условие чтобы этого не было - при наличии кол-ва строк более указанного?

Comment: **прикрутить условие** - ключ *-n* у команды  *tail*.